# AWS S3 copy assets between two buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, copy

With the command line interface I can copy files between two buckets.

```
$ aws s3 sync s3://mybucket-src s3://mybucket-target --exclude *.tmp
```

This will copy from one source bucket to another target bucket. But I want to copy file types (images, documents, videos) to their respective folders in target bucket.

1. Images go into source_files/images
2. Documents go into source_files/pdf
3. Videos go into source_files/videos

Also as soon as if new files hit source bucket, they should be copied to their respective folders in target bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You have two topics in your question:

- Moving objects to different locations based on their type
- Moving objects as soon as they appear

The ability to do something as soon as an object is created can be done by configuring an **Amazon S3 Event**. The event can trigger an AWS Lambda function, send a message to an Amazon SNS topic or put a message into an Amazon SQS queue.

For your use-case, you would use an **AWS Lambda function**. The function should:

- Retrieve the `bucket name` and `Key` of the object from the provided `event` record
- Retrieve metadata about the object via `HeadObject()`
- Issue a `CopyObject()` command to copy the object to a desired location based upon the metadata

For an example of triggering a Lambda function when an S3 object is created, see: [Tutorial: Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3 - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html)

Comment: This looks like a feasible solution. I will try to implement it through lambda function in java sdk.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows powershell:

```
  aws s3 ls  s3://bucket-source | ForEach-Object -Process {[System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_).Split(".")[1]} | ForEach-Object -Process {aws s3 sync s3://bucket-source s3://bucket-destination/$_/ --exclude "*" --include  "*.$_" }
```

Explanation:

1. Get the list of files in source bucket

   aws s3 ls  s3://bucket-source
2. find their extensions

   ForEach-Object -Process {[System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_).Split(".")[1]}
3. copy to the destination bucket. It creates folders for each extension and copy that type of files to it:

   ForEach-Object -Process {aws s3 sync s3://bucket-source s3://bucket-destination/$*/ --exclude "*" --include  "*.$*"

Comment: but how this code will be triggered on event ? Also I don't want to create folder in destination bucket. Folders are already there.

Comment: @mohitkumar Please note that "folders" do not actually exist in Amazon S3. You can actually copy a file to a folder that does not exist and the folder will "appear" to exist.